# White space in right margin when using firefox

Tags: html, css

Have some unwanted white space in the right margin when viewing the site with firefox.  Problem doesn't occur with other browsers.

I've tried putting a 2px border around all elements to see if there's a hidden div, but there doesn't seem to be.

The link to the page is  . . .

http://msmdesignz-testing.info/wp/

Thanks.

Comment: what elements you're talking about?

Comment: You may want to clean up your HTML. There are 69 errors.

Comment: @EricEgana A screenshot, or a more detailed description, would go a long way.

Comment: I thought there might be a dive on the side that was taking up that white space, so I temporarily put a border around all page elements, just to see if there was a container on the right.  But there isn't, so I took off the temporary border

Comment: How are you calculating the left and right area width that's around the main content?  The main content has the "Digistar media helps you, etc" and to the left there is like a margin or something.  There's an equal margin on the right hand side.  This makes since, your just centering the content.  The reason I'm bringing all that up though, is it looks like the extra what space is exactly the same width... almost like something is being calculated twice...?

Comment: I was thinking it might have something to do with the margins, but it seems like they are all set to 0.  Someone mentioned a facebook iframe, so maybe i should look into that.

Answer (score 0):

There's an Facebook iframe that's being injected into the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in your page.  That iframe (that's identified as iframe id="fabb7e18d7b7ca" class="FB_UI_Hidden") has an inline style width="575px" that is causing the extra white space on the right side of your page in FF.

You'll need to find a way to eliminate that width definition.  Adding a style cascade somewhere in your css like this: `.FB_UI_Hidden { width: 100px !important; }` (or with an appropriate width) would resolve your problem.

Comment: how did you identify the iframe?

Comment: Using the Firebug extension for Firefox you can see everything going on in the rendered page code, even things that get injected by scripting.  Exploring with Firebug was how I identified the particular iframe in your page.

Comment: I've added an addition to my answer with a proposed way to correct your problem.

Comment: Ah, I see it.  I guess the elements that show up dimly are hidden.  I'm relatively new to this . . . any suggestions on how to eliminate iframes?  And thanks for getting back to me.